# Does every user have a user.ID?

Tags: user-profile

Does every user that belongs to a site collection or a group in that site collection, have a user.ID?

I am iterating through a list of SPFieldUserValueCollection and am comparing the SPFieldUserValue.User.ID with the SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID and want to make sure they will compare accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, every user will have an ID. [SPUser.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.id.aspx) is the integer ID of the user in the site collection. However, the ID is specific only to that specific site collection.

I would recommend using [SPUser.LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.loginname.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

SPUser.ID only refers to the Item ID of their entry in that site collection's User Information List, so it's never guaranteed to be unique across a farm.

Comment: I understand it might not be unique across farms, but do you know if ever user in that farm will have an ID regardless if they are a member of the farm or just member of a group that belongs to the farm?

Comment: I would clarify that it isn't even unique across site collections.

Comment: @Kit yeah, that's what I meant, though I guess how I wrote it could infer that I meant that it could be unique within a web app. Which it isn't. :)