# Assign two users to a SharePoint 2013 workflow task

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server, tasks, user-accounts

I want to assign a couple of users to a task in a SP 2013 workflow task that is developed via Visual Studio 2012.

I tried assigning `i:0#.w|mydomain\\spfarm;i:0#.w|mydomain\\muhammedh` and I got the below mentioned error:

```
System.ArgumentException: AssignedTo at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Since this can Achieved via the UI, Im sure that there has to be a way.

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried assigning to the users' integer IDs instead? E.g. `23; 29`

Comment: @Submits Nope. I'm on it now.

Comment: Looks like that will not be a suitable solution... Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14145/does-every-user-have-a-user-id